# How to fix "malformed entry 50 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)"?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was attempting to follow the instructions for installing Docker on Ubuntu when this command broke my apt-get, so now whenever I try to run it (currently trying to install lsb-release), I receive the following errors:

Malformed entry 50 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
The list of sources could not be read.
Malformed entry 50 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
The list of sources could not be read.

Here is line 50:

````
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu stable```
````

Answer (score 0):

The format should be:

```
address disto folder/build(s)
```

So for example:

```
deb-src https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/ bionic stable
```

Where bionic is the distro and stable is the folder/build